# Debug Installed version - C#

Tags: c#, debugging

I am basically trying to debug the installed version of our software by replacing the installed dll with a debug version of the same dll.

What do I need to do, to debug the installed version of my app.

1. The dll file which I need to replace, exists in GAC.
2. The installed version number is different to the debug version number.
3. I am pretty sure (havent checked), installed version has a strong name, unsure about debug version.

Comment: What's the question / problem?

Comment: The question apparently is how to replace the production dll with the debug version without breaking the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real question here, but it is clear that you are likely having problems make it work:

- The app is going to find the DLL that's in the GAC first.  So you'll want to unregister it and copy your debug version in the same directory as the app's EXE so it always loads your replacement.  Registering the debug version in the GAC is technically possible but see the next bullet.
- The app is going to look for a specific [AssemblyVersion] and is not going to be very happy finding another one in your replacement.  Clearly you want to give your debug version the same [AssemblyVersion] so that's not a problem.  You could add a `<bindingRedirect>` in the app.exe.config file if really necessary.
- The app *might* check the strong name of your replacement DLL if it doesn't run in full trust.  So be sure to sign it with the same key and skip a headache with that.

Comment: the problem i had was the dll i was replacing in gac turned out to be a 32 bit replacing 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the "Debug" as well as the "Release" version. What are required are the ".pdb" files. The "Release" version has the disadvantage that some code might have been optimized away, making debugging less conclusive.

Here is a nice Article, which describes how an Assembly in the GAC can be debugged: http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=23

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
However, i first need to replace the old installed dll with this new version, and then debug. When I replace the dll, the service fails to even start. What am i missing?

Before I replace in GAC,
1. Do I need to match versions of old and new dll, will plain copy work?
2. Do I need to have a strong name. If old dll had a strong name, should new have one too?

I understand there can be compatibility issues too, I would like to know if this is a compatibility issue or one of above.
p.s.
I am aware that I can debug the release version, but I do not have its associated pdb.